# Как правильно составить запрос?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.id_user,
    t1.parent_id,
    t1.text, 
    t1.date
FROM comments t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
       tt2.id,
       tt2.id_user,
       tt2.parent_id,
       tt2.text, 
       tt2.date 
    FROM 
       comments tt2.
    WHERE 
       tt2.parent_id = 0
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT ".$start.", ".$colCom."
) t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id or t1.id = t2.id 
ORDER BY t1.date, t1.parent_id ASC
```

Этот запрос выбирает родительские комментарии (tt2.parent_id = 0) в колличестве, опрелённой переменной $colCom и все их ответы на них (детей). У каждого комментария (и родителя, и ребёнка) есть id юзера который оставил комментарий (t1.id_user, tt2.id_user). Есть таблица `users`, в кот. хранятся имена, аватарки этих юзеров. Как выбрать данные и из таблицы users `WHERE t1.id_user = users.id && tt2.id_user = users.id`

Пробовал второй JOIN прикрутить. Ну не получается и всё!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Считайте, что у вас уже есть таблица комментариев (t1) с необходимым количеством комментариев. Дальше работаете с ней, присоединяете к ней все что нужно

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.id_user,
    t1.parent_id,
    t1.text, 
    t1.date,
    u.avatar,
    u.username
FROM comments t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
       tt2.id
    FROM 
       comments tt2
    WHERE 
       tt2.parent_id = 0
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT ".$start.", ".$colCom."
) t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id or t1.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t1.id_user = u.id
ORDER BY t1.date, t1.parent_id ASC
```

ЗЫ И во внутреннем запросе не нужны дополнительные поля. там вытаскиваются только id-шники родительских комментариев.

Comment: Огромное спасибо,Юрий. Наконец-то.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос. Как в этом же запросе посчитать кол-во ответов для каждого родителя и тоже прикрутить LIMIT ?

Comment: Так:

    select 
    ...
    cnt.subcomment_count
    ...
    left join (select count(*) as subcomment_count, parent_id from comments group by parent_id) cnt ON t1.id = cnt.parent_id

Comment: SELECT t1.id, t1.id_user, t1.parent_id, t1.text, t1.date, u.avatar, u.username, cnt.subcomment_count FROM comments t1 
JOIN (SELECT tt2.id FROM comments tt2 
WHERE tt2.parent_id = 0
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT ".$start.", ".$colCom.") t2 
ON t1.parent_id = t2.id or t1.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t1.id_user = u.id
ORDER BY t1.date, t1.parent_id ASC, 
left join (select count(*) as subcomment_count, parent_id from comments group by parent_id) cnt ON t1.id = cnt.parent_id

Не хочет работать. Куда-то я не туда вставляю left join

Comment: вот так:

    SELECT
    t1.id, t1.id_user, t1.parent_id, t1.text, t1.date, u.avatar, u.username, cnt.subcomment_count
    FROM comments t1
      JOIN (SELECT tt2.id FROM comments tt2 WHERE tt2.parent_id = 0 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$colCom.") t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id OR t1.id = t2.id
      LEFT JOIN users u ON t1.id_user = u.id
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS subcomment_count, parent_id FROM comments GROUP BY parent_id) cnt ON t1.id = cnt.parent_id
    ORDER BY t1.date, t1.parent_id ASC

order by всегда в конце.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Правда я так и не понял как это Вы вставили эту запись. Будем разбираться. По второй части вопроса: LIMIT к таблице t1 прикрутить-то можно? Дабы ответы на комментарии выбирались допустим по 4 штуки. Нужно для того, что бы остальные ответы загружались по требованию юзера. (по клику)

Comment: LIMIT тут нету, да... Это другая задача.
Раз так, я бы на вашем месте грузил бы сначала нулевой уровень, отображал, потом по клику пользователя подгружал ответы на этот комментарий, тогда и количеством управлять проще и грузить меньше. Правда кликать многовато придется. В общем нужно выработать какую-то идею интерфейса. Один запрос из другого тут не вытекает, так просто добавлением строчки в запрос не обойдешься.